# Did the US request that Russia extradite the 13 Russians charged by Mueller?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, espionage, mueller-investigation

On Friday February 16th, 2018, the office of special council announced indictments of 13 Russian Federation nationals with the crimes of fraud against the United States.  According to [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2018/02/19/politics/russia-denies-us-meddling-intl/index.html), Russia has officially denied any involvement in the alleged crimes.

Despite the currently-tense relationship between Russia and the US, the 2 countries still maintain diplomatic relations and both claim to cooperate in the areas thwarting criminal activity.  Specifically, both countries have listed incidents in which law enforcement agencies informed their counterparts in efforts to thwart terrorist acts.

I would like to know **if anyone knows** (or can provide any links to any information) **whether the US has made formal extradition requests to Russia for the Russian nationals charged with these crimes**.  I would really appreciate not having answers of the "what would be the point" kind.  I am asking if it has happened.  *I am not claiming it would be successful*.

Firstly, it would allow Russia to prove its innocence (if it is indeed not involved).  Secondly, it would also follow the standard jurisprudence practice in cases of people formally accused of crimes.  And lastly, **it would demonstrate that the charges were made in earnest** (which is necessary to prevent any future accusations of showmanship that would be made given the political nature of the investigation).

Comment: Please note that even if not extradited, their lives got severely restricted. They cannot travel (safely: they can only if are willing to take chances) to any country which has extradition agreements with USA. So no more vacations in Spain, or shopping trips to London. And any property in such countries might be seized too. I would assume that the oligarch has at least one vacation home someplace warm.

Comment: And more complications: say Tunisia has no extradition agreement, so they go to a vacation there. On the flight back, when overflying Italy, they have engine problems and have to land in emergency. OOPS! Or plane might be requested to land.

Answer (score 17):

[Article here](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/feb/16/robert-mueller-russians-charged-election)

> All were charged with conspiracy to defraud the United States. Three
>   defendants were charged with conspiracy to commit wire fraud and bank
>   fraud, and five defendants were charged with aggravated identity
>   theft.
>
> Separately, Mueller’s office announced that Richard Pinedo, of Santa
>   Paula, California, had pleaded guilty to identity fraud. Pinedo, 28,
>   admitted to running a website that offered stolen identities to help
>   customers get around the security measures of major online payment
>   sites. It was not made clear whether his service had been used by the
>   Russian operatives.
>
> Rosenstein said no contact had been made with Russian authorities
>   regarding the charges so far, **but that US officials intended to seek**
>   **extradition of the defendants**.

As you said, whether Russia complies remains to be seen and all signs so far point towards not-likely.

> Russian foreign ministry spokeswoman Maria Zakharova called the
>   allegations “absurd”.

Logically, seeking extradition is the only thing that makes sense because that's the whole point of the investigation.   If the crimes were small, it's possible they wouldn't seek extradition, but in this case, I think it's a given.

It may not have officially happened yet, but it will, even if it's not likely to be granted.

Comment: Worth adding that Russia's Constitution specifically forbids extradition. Article 61 "The citizen of the Russian Federation may not be deported out of Russia or extradited to another state."

Comment: @SGR - that shoud be an answer

Comment: @grovkin Which is why it's not a full answer, and more to expand upon your point of "whether Russia complies remains to be seen"